# Using snap.js to toggle a pane from the bottom

Tags: javascript, snap.js

Snap.js is great, but would it be possible to have it toggle a pane sliding in from the bottom  instead of from the right or left? Basically what I need is:

`snapper.expand('bottom');`

If it's not possible using snap.js, do you have other recs?